# How actually work alter table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, postgresql-11

I had a problem with restarting my code:

My code contains

```
alter table sch1.t1 set schema sch2;
```

I get an error

> relation t1 already exists in schema sch2

I try to add if exists, implying that if t1 not in sch1 (already in sch2) it will be skip. But

it gave me the same problem.

Then I found a view with name t1.   I drop the view and create with another name and my problem solved.

So, why PostgeSQL catch an error with `alter table` on view? How does it work? Why not only for table?

Comment: Well, it's rather obvious... If the schema `sch` could contain both `t1` table and `t1` view, what would mean `select * from sch.t1`?

Answer (score 1):

Schemas are namespaces, and tables and views are some of the objects that can be created within them. The namespace is not sub-partitioned any further by object type, meaning it is an error to try to create a view and a table with the same name in the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

The message is saying, the destination table already exists!
From psql, if you run `\d sch2.t1` can see the table?

Try, dropping the destination table before the alter.